# SQL Server 2008 max columns and rows max size 

Tags: sql-server-2008

Using SQL server 2008, I'm trying to insert more than 1024 column into a table.

I tried using a SPARSE column, but I got another problem with the max size of the row 8k which also the row size exceeds this boundary.

I also read that we can not use row compression with SPARSE column.

I searched a lot but actually till now I didn't get a solution.

Anyone could help

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need that many columns? What table structure are you trying to create?

Comment: It sounds like you need to rethink the schema? You'll probably find that even if you do need that many columns in a table, it'll be a query nightmare when it comes to finding data.

Answer (score 1):

The 1024 is [a correct limitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) of the total column number in a usual non-wide table that is due to the row size, as you point out yourself in your question.

The work-around is to use so-called [wide tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986.aspx). The trick is here that instead of columns one uses so-called [column sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280521.aspx) to define the columns. Thereby you can increase the total column number up to 30'000.

**EDIT**:

In my original answer I somehow discarded the important part of your question, namely that you already have problems with the row size, not with the column numbers. This means, that your sparse columns are not "sparse" enough. The only way to cope with the problem would be them vertical partitioning of your data, e.g. splitting your large table into two or three smaller tables...

Comment: Sparse columns / wide tables are only suitable when most of the column values are `NULL`. As indicated in the question this is not the case because they are hitting the row limit.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I see nowhere in the question that this is the case. On the contrary, they state in the question that they tried to use sparse columns already **and still** them bump into the limitation. Sparse columns alone won't make your table wide, that is why I tried to point this out in my answer.

Comment: Did you read your own link about wide tables? "The maximum size of a wide table row is 8,019 bytes. Therefore, most of the data in any particular row should be NULL."

Comment: Thanks everybody for your reply...i really do need to come over this issue as soon as possible
the business actually is about Survey system .. these lots of columns due to the huge number of questions 
and this huge size of a row is the respondents of the persons 

for a reason of having a BI solution, this is the Fact table we are talking about which have some measures, i can not split it into 2 or more tables..

Answer (score 0):

*Will not observe the case that your DB schema is well thougth out...*

1. You cannot create the table with more than 1024 non-sparse columns
2. You can have more than 8k data in row using consequent updates of
   the same row with different column sets, as in following example

   ```
   CREATE TABLE dbo.temp
   (
   Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   varchar1 VARCHAR(8000) NULL,
   varchar2 VARCHAR(8000) NULL,
   varchar3 VARCHAR(8000) NULL,
   varchar4 VARCHAR(8000) NULL,
   varchar5 VARCHAR(8000) NULL
   )
   GO
   INSERT INTO dbo.temp DEFAULT VALUES --just to get an Id

   DECLARE @Id INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

   UPDATE dbo.temp SET
       varchar1 = REPLICATE('1', 8000)
   WHERE Id = @Id

   UPDATE dbo.temp SET
       varchar2 = REPLICATE('2', 8000)
   WHERE Id = @Id

   UPDATE dbo.temp SET
       varchar3 = REPLICATE('3', 8000)
   WHERE Id = @Id

   UPDATE dbo.temp SET
       varchar4 = REPLICATE('4', 8000)
   WHERE Id = @Id

   UPDATE dbo.temp SET
       varchar5 = REPLICATE('5', 8000)
   WHERE Id = @Id
   ```

Comment: You can insert the row with only one column for example, get an Id of row and after that run couple of UPDATE statements of row with the given Id. I'll add an another answer with the example right now

Comment: @OlegDok - There is no need to do this in separate updates. `varchar` data can be stored off row anyway but it still needs space for a pointer to the data stored in row. The OP simply has too many columns for  this to work. The space consumed by the pointer will mean you hit the row limit well before you get up to 1024 columns.

Comment: @Martin Smith - Yes, as I noticed in very first sentence of answer 8-) But an answer was provided just as an example - how to insert into row more than 8060 bytes